# Space is removing at end of the line

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2

While running the insert script in sql*plus, space is removing. Can you please help us is there any plus command available in Oracle to not remove space at end of the line.

Ex: After the text 'Ameerpet,' we have space in the insert script. I have run this command through sql*plus it was success but in output space got removed.

```
insert into emp values(1,'<p style="font-weight: bold; margin-top: 10px;">Mithrivanam, Ameerpet, 
Hyderabad, Telangana, 500018</p>');
```

Output:

```
<p style="font-weight: bold; margin-top: 10px;">Mithrivanam, Ameerpet,
Hyderabad, Telangana, 500018</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to have that specific space and line break, you should not rely on enviroment settings, but explicitly specify it:

```
insert into emp values(1,'<p style="font-weight: bold; margin-top: 10px;">Mithrivanam, Ameerpet, ' || chr(10) ||
'Hyderabad, Telangana, 500018</p>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Well there must be an 'Enter' after 'Ameerpet, ' which has divided the query into two lines thats causing the problem.
Use the following

```
insert into tbltest values(1,'Mithrivanam, Ameerpet, Hyderabad, Telangana, 00018');
```

Instead of

```
insert into emp values(1,'Mithrivanam, Ameerpet, 
Hyderabad, Telangana, 500018');
```

**Test scenario:**
I have inserted one with an Enter and another without enter(one line) and got the following output.

```
SQL> create table tbltest(id number, code varchar2(200));

Table created.


SQL> desc tbltest;
 Name                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 ID                         NUMBER
 CODE                           VARCHAR2(200)


SQL> insert into tbltest values(1,'<p style="font-weight: bold; margin-top: 10px;">Mithrivanam,  Ameerpet, 
Hyderabad, Telangana, 500018</p>'); 2 <<<here, this '2' indicates we have got two lines.

1 row created.

SQL> select * from tbltest;

<p style="font-weight: bold; margin-top: 10px;">Mithrivanam,  Ameerpet,
Hyderabad, Telangana, 500018</p>


    ID
----------
CODE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     1
<p style="font-weight: bold; margin-top: 10px;">Mithrivanam,  Ameerpet,<<<here not space
Hyderabad, Telangana, 500018</p>

SQL> insert into tbltest values(1,'<p style="font-weight: bold; margin-top: 10px;">Mithrivanam,  Ameerpet,   Hyderabad, Telangana, 00018</p>');

1 row created.

SQL> select * from tbltest;

    ID
----------
CODE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     1
<p style="font-weight: bold; margin-top: 10px;">Mithrivanam,  Ameerpet,   Hydera
bad, Telangana, 00018</p>
```

**Solution:** Don't break that line of text(string of html tags) into two lines.

Comment: Thanks JSapkota for the response. We will not change the data type, currently the data type of the column is clob. Can you please let us know if any alternative/

Comment: @Surendra and i have tested it with clob its working perfectly. Just dont press enter after 'Ameerpet, ' meaning make that html code of one line. OR if you need the space explicitly with the line breakbreak Balazs Papp's answer would be better.